# Change ViewControllers on Orientation change in runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I want to change the ViewControllers On Screen orientation change

I have only one class ViewController and two StoryboardBased UIViewControllers.

```
  UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Portrait" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    else {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Landscape" owner:self options:nil];
    }
```

This code can be used to to load different xib upon orientation change. But How can I load different Controllers in Xib File on orientation changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you follow this approach then you do not load different view controllers in xib. One xib represents one view with its subviews.

However, I would follow another aproach. I would create a view A (self.view of a "host" view controller) which has nothing but two fullscreen container views, one for landscape and one for portrait. 
Just make both autoresizing so that they always occupy the full screen.

Upon rotation evets I whould just hide and unhide them accordingly.

But why do you think that you need individual view controllers for each rotation?

Comment: What about the animation, won't it look odd?

Comment: You could animate the hiding and unhiding. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this way

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];   
     }

     -(void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
      {
           UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

           if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))
           {
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Portrait" owner:self options:nil];            
           }
           else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
           {
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Landscape" owner:self options:nil];
           }
      }
```

hope this will help you......

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach here is to use the [view controller containment api](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html). What you should do is have a wrapper view controller that embeds two views from 2 view controllers (one for each orientation) and using the methods provided by the iOS API to [respond to orientation change](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html) you switch between views